# Ways to Pass around a ball

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Five people are passing a ball amongst themselves. The ball starts with Alonzo. Each person who has the ball passes it onto someone else. After the eighth pass, the ball returns to Alonzo. Find the number of possible sequences of passes.

I know that since there are 8 passes, there are $4^8$ ways of passing the ball when there are no restrictions and after $7$ passes there would be $4^6$ ways to pass the ball back to Alonzo. How do I continue?

Comment: What does this have to do with fibonacci numbers?

Comment: "to someone else" means not to himself and (supposedly) not to Alonzo.  So the sequence is $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \, \cdots \, \cdot 3 \cdot 1$

Comment: @GCab I see no reason to assume that "Each person who has the ball passes it onto someone else" means "to someone else who isn't Alonzo."

Comment: @Arthur: .."to someone else who isn't Alonzo" and then not himself either .. or not ?

Comment: @GCab  I am assuming that the rules just preclude tossing the ball to yourself.  Thus a possible good string of length $8$ (not counting the initial $A$) would be $(A)BABCABCA$.  To be sure, if it is prohibited to throw the ball to $A$ then the answer is $0$.

Comment: @lulu: my understanding of the rules is that the strings like $(A)BCBCDCB \to A$ are allowed, with no $A$ in between and no consecutive same characters

Comment: @GCab  Fair enough, but of course that one is easy to count.  We get $4$ choices initially and then $3$ choices a time until $A$ demands the ball back.

Comment: @lulu: under my interpretation, that would be in fact the number of different configurations.

Comment: the ball can be passed to anyone including alonzo but alonzo can't have the ball on the 7th pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's work recursively, restricting to those paths that start with $A$ (we put $A$ in the $0^{th}$ slot of the string).

Let $a_n$ be the number of paths of length $n$ that end in $A$.  To fix the notation, let's say that the initial $A$ is not counted in the length.  So, we have $a_1=0$ for example, since we can't put $A$ in slot $1$.

Let $b_n$ be the number of paths of length $n$ that do not end in $A$.  Then, $b_1=4$ for example.

As you remark, we have $$a_n+b_n=4^n$$

Recursively, we have $$a_n=b_{n-1}\quad \&\quad b_n=4a_{n-1}+3b_{n-1}=4^n-b_{n-1}$$

That's already enough to solve your problem, and we get $$\boxed{a_8=13108}$$  A little extra work shows that $$a_n=\frac {4^n+4\times (-1)^n}5$$

Comment: when I plugged in n = 8 into the equation I got 13108 instead of 3276

Comment: @kquinn  Yes, you are right.   $a_7=3276$, not $a_8$.  I will edit to reflect the error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $a_n$ be the number of possible sequences of $n$ passes, where Alonzo starts with the ball, and Alonzo gets it back after the $n$th pass. Then $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2 = 4$.

Suppose we have a sequences of $n$ passes, where Alonzo starts with the ball, and each person who has the ball passes it onto someone else, but the last pass does not have to be to Alonzo. There are 4 choices for each pass, so there are $4^n$ possible sequences. In $a_n$ of these sequences, Alonzo is the last person to have the ball, which means there are $4^n - a_n$ sequences where Alonzo is not the last person.

Now use recursion. Note that Alonzo can't have the ball on the $n-1$th pass.